# figuring out the type parameter

Tags: java

I have been learning java in school for about two weeks now, but I'm unsure how to approach this:

```
// Represents a card used to purchase food services at a university
public class FoodServicesCard {
// points needed to get cash-back reward
public static int POINTS_NEEDED_FOR_CASH_BACK = 2000; 
// points earned for each cent charged to card   
public static int REWARD_POINTS_PER_CENT_CHARGED = 1;
// reward in cents    
public static int CASH_BACK_REWARD = 10;                

// add fields to represent changing properties of a food services card
//####################################################################
// -> here is where I start coding, however, I'm uncertain where to start.
}
```

The only one I can think of is **int** but it seems like the card is composed of two int: the reward point, and cash remainder; i'm unsure if there's something that can group two integers together to form something like this...maybe something like: int reward_pt, int cash_remain; using int to represent the structure of the food service card.

Can anyone give me a hint on this? any advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Grouping mutliple variables together is exactly the point of classes and objects. Therefore, your question is a bit unclear to me. Why is your solution "`int reward_pt; int cash_remain;`" not working?

Answer (score 1):

He wants you to add fields to represent changing properties of a food services card. Lets analyze the question:
Fields represent properties of classes. So "fields to represent changing properties" is just a fancy way to say variables that are not static nor final.

So i would just add

```
public int collectedPoints;
public int remainingCash;
```

Better would be private if you have already learned about access modifiers.

If you learned about booleans already perhaps add

```
public boolean expired;
```

Be a little creative ;-)

Aditional Advice:

Use camelcasing for fieldnames. This is common naming convention for java.

Have fun learning java

Comment: Thanks for your advice; here's another quick question
Here we're asked to complete the stub, i'm not sure if I only need to show  remainingCash or I have to use collectedPoints as well. If I need to use both, how should i write this. 
// REQUIRES: initialBalance >= 0
// EFFECTS: constructs food service card with given initial balance in cents and zero reward points

public FoodServicesCard(int initialBalance) {
        // stub
    }

Comment: I think i've figured it out. I wrote: this.collectedPoints = initialBalance; this.remainingCash = 0; for the stub

Answer (score 0):

The fields already defined are static, which means  they are not depending of any particular card, they are class fields and not instance fields.

for adding field to represent changing properties of the cards, the question that we should ask is :

What informations we need to know about **each card** ?

Comment: From the info given by my instructor, I think we need to store two info about the card, one is the cash remainder and the other one is points rewarded; so that later on we can convert the points rewarded to actual cash (2000 points = 10 cents)

Comment: Insert it in code, because even if you did guessed what fields you have to add, the type and keyword (private/public, static,final...) play an important role in declaring a variable